# Threejs - Applying simple texture on a shader material

Tags: three.js, glsl

Using Threejs (67) with a Webgl renderer, I can't seem to get a plane with a shader material to wear its texture. No matter what I do the material would just stay black.

My code at the moment looks quite basic :

```
var grassT = new Three.Texture(grass); // grass is an already loaded image.
grassT.wrapS = grassT.wrapT = Three.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
grassT.flipY = false;
grassT.minFilter = Three.NearestFilter;
grassT.magFilter = Three.NearestFilter;
grassT.needsUpdate = true;

var terrainUniforms = {
  grassTexture : { type: "t", value: grassT},
}
```

Then I just have this revelant part in the vertexShader :

```
vUv = uv;
```

And on the fragmentShader side :

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(grassTexture, vUv);
```

This results in :

- Black material.
- No error in console.
- gl_FragColor value is always (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).

What I tryed / checked:

- Everything works fine if I just apply custom plain colors.
- All is ok if I use vertexColors with plain colors too.
- My texture width / height is indeed a power of 2.
- The image is on the same server than the code.
- Tested others images with same result.
- The image is actually loading in the browser debugger.
- UVS for the mesh are corrects.
- Played around with wrapT, wrapS, minFilter, magFilter
- Adapted the mesh size so the texture has a 1:1 ratio.
- Preloaded the image with requirejs image plugin and created the texture from THREE.Texture() instead of using THREE.ImageUtils();
- Played around with needsUpdate : true;
- Tryed to add defines['USE_MAP'] during material instanciation.
- Tryed to add material.dynamic = true.
- I have a correct rendering loop (interraction with terrain is working).

What I still wonder :

- It's a multiplayer game using a custom port with express + socket.io. Am I hit by any Webgl security policy ?
- I have no lights logic at the moment, is that a problem ?
- Maybe the shader material needs other "defines" at instanciation ?

I guess I'm overlooking something simpler, this is why I'm asking...
Thanks.

Comment: A bit hard to debug without all of your code - but I would definitely suggest adding an AmbientLight to your scene to check if the model actually does have the texture.  I've found that you can often have one texture render ( i.e. grass ) and seem correct, only to realize that you've done it wrong and it's ignoring lighting.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I checked with the light on and it's not better. I did some progress however getting my hands dirty into the renderer code. I found that the texture.needsUpdate property is set to false for some reason ! If I remove the conditional check at line 26278 -setTexture  function- the texture is rendered.

Comment: Therefore the new question is : Where and Why a needsUpdate property of a texture could be set from true to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am applying various effects on the same shader. I have a custom API that merge all different effects uniforms simply by using `Three.UniformsUtils.merge()` However this function is calling the `clone()` method on the texture and this is causing to reset `needsUpdate` to `false` before the texture reach the renderer.

It appears that you should set your texture **`needsUpdate`** property to true when reaching the **material** level. On the texture level, if the uniform you set get merged, and therefore cloned, later in the process, it'll lose its `needsUpdate` property.

The issue is also detailled here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3393

In my case the following *wasn't* working (`grassT` is my texture):

```
grassT.needsUpdate = true
```

while the following is running perfectly later on in the code:

```
material.uniforms.grassTexture.value.needsUpdate = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Image loading is asynchronous. Most likely, you are rendering your scene before the texture image loads.

You must set the `texture.needsUpdate` flag to `true` *after* the image loads. three.js has a utility that will do that for you:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "texture.jpg" );
```

Once rendered, the renderer sets the `texture.needsUpdate` flag back to `false`.

three.js r.68

Comment: Thank you for that. I tryed that way with the same result. The image is actually loaded when the code runs. The problem is coming from elsewhere : I am applying various effects on the same shader. I have a custom API that merge all different effects uniforms simply by using : Three.UniformsUtils.merge(); However this function call clone() method on the texture and this is causing to reset needsUpdate to false before the texture reach the renderer !!

Comment: It appears that you should set your texture needsUpdate property to true when reaching the material level because on the texture level, if the uniform you set get merged (and therefore cloned) later in the process, it'll lose its needsUpdate property !

In my case this WASN'T working (grassT is my texture) :

    grassT.needsUpdate = true

while the following is running perfectly :

    material.uniforms.grassTexture.value.needsUpdate = true;

Comment: Hey WestLangley ! This is very familiar to you afterall : I was just hit by : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3393

Comment: Please provide all the information necessary to answer your question in your original post.

Comment: I sure will. I need to wait 3 additionnal hours because my reputation is too low. With less than 10 points we can only reply to ourselves after 8 hours.